# ConstraintLayout take height of another view android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using `constraintLayout`

I wanted one of my view to take height of another view

I wanted my right `Textview` to take the height of left `TextView`

**My code :**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_curved"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cal_consumed"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_cal_burnt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/con_info" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cal_burnt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_curved"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cal_burnt"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed" />
```

**Current output:**

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change the `layout_height` to `0dp` (match constraints) for `tv_cal_burnt`. That will cause the `TextView` to grow to the same height as the other view. Your top and bottom constraints are already set correctly to make this work. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints).

> Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cal_burnt"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
   ...
```

---

---

**Update:** If you don't know in advance which view will be taller/wider due to localization, etc., I suggest taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630534/6287910) to a similar question. The concept outlined in that answer works for heights and widths - just interchange `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` for `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"`. (As of *ConstraintLayout* 2.0.4)

Comment: This will cause issues with localization. If in another language tv_cal_burnt is bigger than tv_cal_consumed, the same problem will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try minimum height of the text view.

```
android:minLines = "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a7a7a7"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="calorie Consumed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_cal_burnt" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cal_burnt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#a7a7a7"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".1"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Calorie Burnt"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_cal_consumed" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you want to make text as center   use `android:gravity="center"` Instance of this  `android:gravity="start"`

I hope this may help you.

Output here:

[image]

Comment: The question is about making height equal not truncating text.

Comment: @karthikkolanji try this let me know,Which is your parent layout for this both textview.

Comment: ConstraintLayout

Comment: @karthikkolanji hey did you check.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution depends on if you feel comfortable making the assumption that the left button is always bigger.

If so, constrain the top of the right button to the top of the left button, and the bottom of the right button to the bottom of the left button ;)