# constraint layout - Two views with largest width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a layout (using constraint layout) like the following:

[image]

In different languages Button1 may be larger than button2. How can I do this?

I've only been able to achieve this using a LinearLayout inside the constraint that contains the two buttons, but I'm trying to use only a layout.

Thanks

Comment: post your xml which is working for linearlayout !! 
I will help you to convert it into constraintlayout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**

I want to mention that Remq's answer works and gets around the self-reference problem I noted below where a view's width is determined by the location of a barrier that uses the same view as a referenced id. The key seems to be the specification of `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` for both views. It is unclear to me why this works, or that it will continue to work, but I wanted to make note of it

**Update #2**

I took another look at why Remq's answer works. My experience is that without specifying `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` for the views, both views collapse to zero width. Once the views measure out as zero width, `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` grows them again so the contents are wrapped. This is just what I surmise and have no proof that this is what is going on, but it makes sense.

---

---

I have seen questions akin to this one on Stack Overflow a number of times. These questions never have a satisfactory answer IMO (including ones that I have answered.) The difficulty is that there is a dependency problem since one view depends on the width of another but that other view depends on the width of the first. We fall into a referential quandary. (Forcing widths programmatically is always an option but seems undesirable.)

Another and, probably, better approach is to use a custom *ConstraintHelper* that will inspect the sizes of the referenced views and adjust the width of all views to the width of the largest.

The custom *ConstraintHelper* is placed in the XML for the layout and references the effected views as in the following sample layout:

**activity_main**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button2 may be larger"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1" />

    <com.example.constraintlayoutlayer.GreatestWidthHelper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1,button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The custom *ConstraintHelper* looks like this:

**GreatestWidthHelper**

```
class GreatestWidthHelper @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintHelper(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun updatePostMeasure(container: ConstraintLayout) {
        var maxWidth = 0

        // Find the greatest width of the referenced widgets.
        for (i in 0 until this.mCount) {
            val id = this.mIds[i]
            val child = container.getViewById(id)
            val widget = container.getViewWidget(child)
            if (widget.width > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = widget.width
            }
        }

        // Set the width of all referenced view to the width of the view with the greatest width.
        for (i in 0 until this.mCount) {
            val id = this.mIds[i]
            val child = container.getViewById(id)
            val widget = container.getViewWidget(child)
            if (widget.width != maxWidth) {
                widget.width = maxWidth

                // Fix the gravity.
                if (child is TextView && child.gravity != Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
                    // Just toggle the gravity to make it right.
                    child.gravity = child.gravity.let { gravity ->
                        child.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY
                        gravity
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout displays as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
However, until this is easyly supported by ContraintLayout I'll use the LinearLayout solution.

Comment: @Mateu The LinearLayout solution is acceptable (IMO), but some would object to the departure from a flat layout.

Comment: Instead of creating a verbose bullcr*p just to make something work in `ConstraintLayout`, it is better to avoid using it

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon this question and was able to solve it with `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier` which were introduced in `1.1.0-beta1` of constraint layout. So I thought it'd be nice to share with people who run into the same issue:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button2 may be larger"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrierEnd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1,button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Haven't been able to center them horizontally, so if someone figures that out I'll update this example.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understand from your question, below code will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```