# ConstraintLayout spread views inside with same width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I want to have a horizontal alignment of four buttons with these conditions:

- their texts are 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% (so the last one will be wider)
- they should have same width
- they should spread the through the remaining space

Is it possible to achieve this using ConstraintLayout?

To demonstrate what I exactly want, take a look at current state of my layout (which is ok):
[image]

The buttons currently are set to have a width of 25 percent of the parent and there's a **static** margin between them (implemented using a LinearLayout). What is the problem? It's possible in small screens that the margin cause the last button to be truncated (like the image below), or in large screens the buttons be so large.

[image]

**So I want the spread behavior of ConstraintLayout besides width of the last button be `wrap_content` and width of other buttons be set equal to the last button.**

Comment: if you want to use same in linearlayout specify dimentions in dimen.xml under xdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and have it category specific size it will not break in diffrennt devices

Comment: @NehaRathore yeah this could be a way of doing it but I prefer a way that is more dynamic and can take advantage of `wrap_content`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/6287910) is one solution to  question that is asked many times on Stack Overflow. Keep an eye out on new releases of _ConstraintLayout_ in case there is an official solution.

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks. it seems that this is the cleanest way of achieving this. I could set your solution as answer if you posted it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but it's already an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @cheticamp and his answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/2912553), the best way of achieving the desired behavior would be writing a simple `ConstraintHelper` which sets width of all the children to the maximum among them.

```kotlin
class MaxWidthConstraint @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintHelper(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    override fun updatePostMeasure(container: ConstraintLayout) {
        val maxWidth =
            referencedIds.asSequence().map { container.getViewById(it) }
                .map { container.getViewWidget(it) }
                .map { it.width }
                .max() ?: 0
        referencedIds.asSequence().map { container.getViewById(it) }
            .map { container.getViewWidget(it) }
            .forEach { it.width = maxWidth }
    }
}
```

So the layout code would be:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25%"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_50"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50%"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_75"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_75"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="75%"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_100"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_50"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100%"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_75"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.myapplication.widgets.MaxWidthConstraint
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_25,btn_50,btn_75,btn_100"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="25%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_50"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="50%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_25"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_75"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_75"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="75%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_50"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_100"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_100"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="100%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_75"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

**Explanation:** I've used app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread".Using chain takes the margin into account while spreading the views evenly.

Comment: Thank for your answer Tayyab. But it still has the same problem of static 16dp of margin. I want to margin be reduced or disappeared when there's not enough space.

Comment: That'll require some java coding. You'd have to measure screen width and width of views, then set the margin accordingly. I'll see if i can try.

Comment: Yeah, but I was looking for a way (if exists) with XML and constraint layout. If not I should just set width of the other buttons equal to the last one during runtime

Comment: You can't make margin dynamic within XML.

Answer (score 0):

> Using chain style spread might be you got your expected layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/entercode_default"
        android:text="25%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_50"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/entercode_default"
        android:text="50%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_75"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/entercode_default"
        android:text="75%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_100"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_50"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/entercode_default"
        android:text="100%"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_75"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The chain itself doesn't make their widths equal. If you remove padding from your buttons you'll see that they aren't equal.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar : Which padding are you talking about?

Comment: I mean default paddings of the buttons.