# How to display both the cardviews of equal sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to display two cards of equal size, one of the CardViews will display the image and another will display TextView. Currently both the CardViews are of different sizes as shown in the image[image]

How can I make both the card views of equal size and make the display side by side at an equal margin from start and end? Below is the code.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardImagePractise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPractise"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardTextPractise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPractise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Random Name"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Related: [ConstraintLayout spread views inside with same width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61866744/208273)

Comment: Did you try setting match_parent both cards ?

Comment: With match_parent GridLayout should manage them properly

Answer (score 0):

In cardview the weight attribute cannot be applied. You can nest the cardview inside a LinearLayout

```xml
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--- CARDVIEW HERE !--->
            </LinearLayout>
           
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <!--- CARDVIEW HERE !--->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: GridLayout would be the parent view right?

Comment: That's right and you can make `fill_parent` width of the `cardview`