# Align two TextViews vertically so they are the exact same width

Tags: android, textview

If I have two textviews vertically aligned where either the one OR the other could contain the longer text, how can I vertically align these so their background image LOOKS like it is one complete background for both TextViews (so one big box no matter which of those views contains the longer text)

Reason is that I use the textviews on top of a picture but need to shadow them in case the picture has the same color as the textview

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As the comments suggested I now used a linear layout like this, but now there is a very small gap between the textviews that wasn't there with ConstraintLayout. Any idea how to fix?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_overlay_top"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textColor="?colorOnPrimary"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_overlay_bottom"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:text="TextVie2 long"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image: After Linear Layout]

**UPDATE 2**

I now used a complete image as background of the linear layout, but sadly this solution does not work either, the linear layout only constraints to the lower text view, which means if the lower is shorter then the upper, the upper one gets truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the two *TextViews* to have the same width regardless of which view has the longer text.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Here is some long, long text."
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrierEnd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

This solution was borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630534/6287910). I took a stab at explaining why it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/6287910).

Comment: `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` THIS is the key. Thank you. I tried 
 `app:layout_constraintWidth="wrap_content"` which did not work. I did not know there is another attribute like this. So no need for nested layouts. Nice

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a vertical LinearLayout, you could set android:layout_width (of the TextViews) to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content".

Edit: Into the outer vertical LinearLayout put an another vertical LinearLayout with android:layout_width="wrap_content" and the 2 TextViews inside with android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: No, they are not supposed to match parent. They are supposed to wrap content because of their background image. The background image should only ever be behind the text and span the area to the end of the other text.

Comment: Ah, now I think you had  the same idea as Wakil. Yes this almost works and yet it was so simple. See the edit

Answer (score 1):

For one big blue background as you said, you can use a vertical LinearLayout as a container of both TextViews and set its background color to blue.

Comment: Actually. Yes! Sometimes it is so simple. I only ever use ConstraintLayout that I do not think of all the old layouts anymore. It works but there is one catch: There is a very small gap between both TextViews so that the background does not seem to be one anymore. I post and update

Comment: I solved it by just using a complete image for the linear layout as background. Thank you

Comment: Actually this does not work either. If you try to put two textviews with match parent into a linear layout with wrap content the linear layout will span the width of the lower text view no matter how long the upper

Answer (score 0):

If you're using constraint layout then
`app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`

would be working for you , also using `baseline` would be very useful too.

Comment: I am using constraint layout and I know how to align the start of both. The question here is how to align both ends so that they are always aligned no matter which one is longer

Comment: wouldn't `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` would be working? if not then can you explain in further details ?

Comment: This does not work because either textview of those could be longer then the other. So both would have to be constrained to the end of the other and both would have a width of 0dp. But this does not work because the api needs at least one length to orient for the 0dp of the other